# What does the name "continuation in part" mean?

Tags: continuation, continuation-in-part

I understand that a "straight" continuation allows for the addition of new claims, but no new matter in the description.

I also understand that a "continuation in part" allows for the addition of both new matter and new claims.

Why does the name of the "broader" continuation suggest that it is the more restrictive of the two?  In other words, what does the "in part" literally mean?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It has two parts: one part is fully supported by the parent and a second part that is new matter. Not fully,  but *In part* it’s a continuation.

Comment: I appreciate the answer, but unless I am misunderstanding I feel like this is just a restatement of my question.  The name "continuation in part" suggests something like "partial continuation" to me.  But the distinction between continuation and continuation in part seems to relate to the presence of new matter or not; CIP is a superset of a continuation.  How does "in part" suggest "new matter?"

Comment: A CIP contains part 1 old material and part 2 new material. So it is two things and one part is a continuation and the other part is not a continuation. So, in part it is a continuation. Part it it is and part of it isn’t.